# mapping URLs in Spring PetClinic sample application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am working with the master branch of  [this version of the spring PetClinic sample application](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-petclinic/).  I added the following method to the OwnerController class:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/catowners", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String findOwnersOfPetType(Map<String, Object> model) {
    // find owners of a specific type of pet
    Integer typeID = 1;//this is just a placeholder
    Collection<Owner> results = this.clinicService.findOwnerByPetType(typeID);
    model.put("selections", results);
    return "owners/catowners";
 }
```

I mapped out the flow of control through the various resources in the application, and seem to have the other code changes I made working, so that now the error that comes up seems to be related to URL mapping.

When I type the following url in my browser:

```
http://localhost:8080/petclinic/owners/catowners
```

I get a 400 error message stating that:

```
"The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect."
```

I want the method above to utilize a file called catowners.jsp, which I located at WEB-INF/jsp/owners/catowners.jsp

Can anyone show me how to fix the code above so that I am able to type in a reasonable url and get the content that is rendered through catowners.jsp?

EDIT:

As per lebolo's request, I am including the entire OwnerController class as follows:

```
package org.springframework.samples.petclinic.web;

@Controller
@SessionAttributes(types = Owner.class)
public class OwnerController {

    private final ClinicService clinicService;

    @Autowired
    public OwnerController(ClinicService clinicService) {
        this.clinicService = clinicService;
    }

    @InitBinder
    public void setAllowedFields(WebDataBinder dataBinder) {
        dataBinder.setDisallowedFields("id");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/owners/new", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String initCreationForm(Map<String, Object> model) {
        Owner owner = new Owner();
        model.put("owner", owner);
        return "owners/createOrUpdateOwnerForm";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/owners/new", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String processCreationForm(@Valid Owner owner, BindingResult result, SessionStatus status) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "owners/createOrUpdateOwnerForm";
        } else {
            this.clinicService.saveOwner(owner);
            status.setComplete();
            return "redirect:/owners/" + owner.getId();
        }
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/owners/find", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String initFindForm(Map<String, Object> model) {
        model.put("owner", new Owner());
        return "owners/findOwners";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/owners", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String processFindForm(Owner owner, BindingResult result, Map<String, Object> model) {

        // allow parameterless GET request for /owners to return all records
        if (owner.getLastName() == null) {
            owner.setLastName(""); // empty string signifies broadest possible search
        }

        // find owners by last name
        Collection<Owner> results = this.clinicService.findOwnerByLastName(owner.getLastName());
        if (results.size() < 1) {
            // no owners found
            result.rejectValue("lastName", "notFound", "not found");
            return "owners/findOwners";
        }
        if (results.size() > 1) {
            // multiple owners found
            model.put("selections", results);
            return "owners/ownersList";
        } else {
            // 1 owner found
            owner = results.iterator().next();
            return "redirect:/owners/" + owner.getId();
        }
    } 
//'''''''''CodeMed added this next method 9/5/2013
    @RequestMapping(value = "/owners/catowners", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String findOwnersOfPetType(Map<String, Object> model) {
        // find owners of a specific type of pet
        Integer typeID = 1;//this is just a placeholder
        Collection<Owner> results = this.clinicService.findOwnerByPetType(typeID);
        model.put("selections", results);
        return "owners/catowners";
     }
//'''''''''''''''''''
    @RequestMapping(value = "/owners/{ownerId}/edit", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String initUpdateOwnerForm(@PathVariable("ownerId") int ownerId, Model model) {
        Owner owner = this.clinicService.findOwnerById(ownerId);
        model.addAttribute(owner);
        return "owners/createOrUpdateOwnerForm";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/owners/{ownerId}/edit", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public String processUpdateOwnerForm(@Valid Owner owner, BindingResult result, SessionStatus status) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "owners/createOrUpdateOwnerForm";
        } else {
            this.clinicService.saveOwner(owner);
            status.setComplete();
            return "redirect:/owners/{ownerId}";
        }
    }

    @RequestMapping("/owners/{ownerId}")
    public ModelAndView showOwner(@PathVariable("ownerId") int ownerId) {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("owners/ownerDetails");
        mav.addObject(this.clinicService.findOwnerById(ownerId));
        return mav;
    }
}
```

Typing in the following url:

```
http://localhost:8080/petclinic/owners/catowners
```

Now gives a 404 message as follows:

```
message /petclinic/WEB-INF/jsp/owners/catowners.jsp  
description The requested resource is not available.
```

However, there is DEFINITELY a file called catowners.jsp located at WEB-INF/jsp/owners/catowners.jsp

Any more suggestions?

SECOND EDIT:

As per Sotirios' question, the following code in mvc-view-config.xml spells out InternalResourceResolver:

```
    <property name="viewResolvers">
        <list>
            <!-- Default viewClass: JSTL view (JSP with html output) -->
          <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
              <!-- Example: a logical view name of 'vets' is mapped to '/WEB-INF/jsp/vets.jsp' -->
              <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
              <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
          </bean>
          <!-- Used here for 'xml' and 'atom' views  -->
          <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver"/>
        </list>
    </property>
```

Comment: It's `catowners` not `catOwners`

Comment: @fujy Yep.  Got that.  But making that change does not cause the error message to go away.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: What's `owners`, did you try to remove it?

Comment: @fujy See my edit above.  I put owners back in.  owners is just a relic from another method in the class, which I copied and edited to create this modified method.  Do you have a solution now that I have posted more code?

Comment: What's the prefix in your `InternalResourceViewResolver` configuration?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I think it is /WEB-INF/jsp/ I put code from the xml config file in a second edit to my posting above.  The config code is straight out of the boilerplate petclinic app at github.  Is there anything else you need?

Comment: @CodeMed Try debugging. We know that your handler method is being hit because it correctly returns the path to the `jsp`. Can only suggest double checking the name of the `jsp` file and its location. With the debugger walk through the stack down to where the `DispatcherServlet` tries to map the `String` returned to a view.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I right clicked on the tomcat server instance in server view in eclipse sts, and chose "Restart in Debug."  Then I right clicked on the root folder for the application in eclipse project explorer and chose "Debug on Server".  But I am not sure where to put my breakpoints.  I am using the exact copy of the petclinic app linked to at the top of my posting, and I added one method in each of three classes (JpaOwnerRepository, OwnerController, and ClinicServiceImpl).  I also added catowners.jsp.  Where should I put my breakpoints?  Should some be outside those changes I made?

Comment: @codeMed Put it inside `findOwnersOfPetType` and follow each debug step as the method returns.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis When I type in http://localhost:8080/petclinic/owners/catowners.jsp I get a message that /petclinic/owners/catowners.jsp is not available.  Similar for http://localhost:8080/petclinic/catowners.jsp .  Variables are not displayed because apparently the breakpoints are not reached in code.  But breakpoints are visible in eclipse debugger breakpoints tab and in code.  What do you suggest I try next?

Comment: You shouldn't be going to `localhost:8080/petclinic/owners/catowners.jsp`, but `localhost:8080/petclinic/owners/catowners` so that the `DispatcherServlet` executes `findOwnersOfPetType`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Of course.  So I next entered it properly and got the 404 message that /petclinic/WEB-INF/jsp/owners/catowners.jsp resource is not available. I put breakpoints on every line of code that I added to the petclinic app, and I clicked resume when code execution hit each line.  What should I be looking for?  Nothing jumped out as an error message until the resource was not found at the end.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36949/discussion-between-sotirios-delimanolis-and-codemed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure which version of the OwnerController you're using. So it may help if you post the whole class (or at least the signature of the class, e.g. any annotations at the class level).

If you're using a version that doesn't have a class level `@RequestMapping` (like [this](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-petclinic/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/samples/petclinic/web/OwnerController.java) one), then your method level mapping should be

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/owners/catowners", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

since your url (post petclinic app context) is `/owners/catowners`

Comment: Thanks.  I actually just changed the name of catOwners.jsp to catowners.jsp and am still getting the same error.

Comment: @CodeMed Thanks, here's another try =)

Comment: +1 for trying to help again.  I just posted the code for OwnerController class in an edit to my original posting above.  It is throwing a 404 error when I give the url you suggested.  Any more suggestions?  Am I missing something?

Comment: I put a link to the version of PetClinic that I am using.  It is at the start of my original posting above.  I just downloaded it from that site yesterday.